# Will a Windows 10 OEM installation disk differ from a "from Microsoft" install?

Tags: windows, installation, oem

So I bought a Windows 10 Home OEM disk for a computer I currently own that is currently running and I'm going to be building two computers using a bunch of old parts for a friend (non-paid). I'm wondering if I can use the OEM disk to install Windows 10 onto the two computers I'm going to build. I'm planning to install it without entering the product key, and then getting them to go to the MS website and buying a product key. Would this work? Does the OEM disk install anything the default MS installer won't, or vice versa?

Comment: Nope they are identical.  Be sure you purchase home not professional

Comment: Just be aware that OEM installs are single shots tied to a mobo once installed.

Comment: @whs - The author understands that.  They just want to install it.  Of course given that anyone with a Windows installation can download the .ISO its not that big of a deal if there is a difference.

Comment: @hoorion - You do understand, when you install Windows 10 on these two new machines, you will have to provide at the time of installation right?

Comment: How do you know that the author understands this. And your last comment is hard to understand. """" you will have to provide at the time of installation right """" What does that mean.

Comment: A license key.  I know the author understands because of how the question is written.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you sure I have to provide the licence key while installing? Can I not just skip the part where I need to enter the license key and have it request a key when you boot up the machine post-install without the installation media?

Comment: I am talking about the machines that have never been activated before....and yes I am 100% sure of that

Answer (score 1):

The OEM disk might include some bundleware, but other than that, there's no difference that will matter. You can use a retail key to activate any Windows installation (provided that the key is for the right edition and OS incarnation, of course). The thing about OEM keys is that they can only be used for a certain motherboard; each motherboard has a serial number that is matched with an OEM key.

#### Optional aside: Generalizing a Windows installation

If you want to actively destroy the product key (and other computer-specific information like driver registration) from a Windows installation, you can run the Sysprep utility that came with Windows in `C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe`. Set the action to boot into OOBE and to generalize, then set the shutdown action to *Shutdown*. Press OK when ready. This will, again, remove all computer-specific information and make the system do the out-of-box experience at next boot, but installed programs and files will be safe.

[image: sysprep]

If you only want the OOBE, don't check *Generalize*. I prep machines for OOBE before I give them to people so that they can have a chance to create their own user account and get the "new computer" feel.

Comment: This seems overkill for somebody who just wants to install Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound The second half is, yes, I just included it in case OP really wanted to produce the "new computer" feel. I updated the answer to make the optional-ness more clear.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, just what I wanted to hear. I actually got the WIN10 install disk from a computer parts retailer, namely [ncix.com](http://ncix.com), so I don't believe the OEM key would be tied to a motherboard.

Comment: You can't buy OEM licenses unless you are an actual OEM like (Dell,HP,etc) so are you sure it's an OEM license and not a retail license?